# QGIS installation making gdalUtils mosaic_raster unable to find gdalinfo?

Tags: r, gdal, qgis

I'm trying to mosaic a group of large rasters using gdalUtils::mosaic_rasters on a Windows 11 machine:

```
mosaic_rasters(gdalfile=single_year, dst_dataset=gdal_mosaic_filename,of="GTiff")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  '"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.16\apps\gdal\share\bash-completion\completions\gdalinfo"' not found
```

I have gone to that location and gdalinfo is in fact present in that location:

```
PS C:\Users\holtd> chdir "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.16\apps\gdal\share\bash-completion\completions"
PS C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.16\apps\gdal\share\bash-completion\completions> ls


    Directory: C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.16\apps\gdal\share\bash-completion\completions


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          1/5/2023   4:16 PM          25134 gdal-config
-a----          1/5/2023   4:16 PM          25134 gdal2tiles.py
-a----          1/5/2023   4:16 PM          25134 gdal2xyz.py
...
-a----          1/5/2023   4:16 PM          25134 gdalimport.py
-a----          1/5/2023   4:16 PM          25134 gdalinfo
-a----          1/5/2023   4:16 PM          25134 gdallocationinfo
...
```

Why is mosaic_rasters trying to use a version of GDAL installed by QGIS, and why isn't it finding gdalinfo even though it's there?

Comment: I'm not sure why that directory is being searched. That `gdalinfo` is not even an executable file ...